# Como imprimir dos listas con dicionarios adentro intercaladas

Tags: python, html5, flask

estoy trayendo desde la base de datos 2 listas que adentro poseen otras listas con al menos un diccionario cada una, que son lo datos que tengo que imprimir en una tabla en HTML.
Estoy utilizando el framework Flask y python 3.9

El problema es que necesito que se imprima primero la primer tabla de la lista1 y luego la primer tabla de la lista2 y así sucesivamente hasta que no haya mas listas con diccionarios.
Como si la primer tabla de la list1 sea un encabezado de la primer tabla de la list2 y así respectivamente.

Ejemplo:

```
list1: [[{'Turno': '3', 'Toma': '03:15', 'Deja': '09:05', 'Apellido': 'Perez', 'Nombre': 'Juan'}],...]

list2: [[{'Tren': 7404, 'Referencia': 'X', 'Origen': 'LLV', 'Sale': '4:06:00', 'Destino': 'PC', 'Llega': '4:34:00', 'Observaciones': None}, 
{'Tren': 3009, 'Referencia': None, 'Origen': 'PC', 'Sale': '5:06:00', 'Destino': 'ZZ', 'Llega': '5:51:00', 'Observaciones': 'PD'}, 
{'Tren': 3042, 'Referencia': None, 'Origen': 'ZZ', 'Sale': '6:09:00', 'Destino': 'PC', 'Llega': '7:02:00', 'Observaciones': None}, 
{'Tren': 3057, 'Referencia': None, 'Origen': 'PC', 'Sale': '7:30:00', 'Destino': 'ZZ', 'Llega': '8:15:00', 'Observaciones': 'PD'}, 
{'Tren': 3090, 'Referencia': None, 'Origen': 'ZZ', 'Sale': '8:33:00', 'Destino': 'LLV', 'Llega': '8:46:00', 'Observaciones': 'R/O 518'}], [{....}]]
```

list1:

| Turno | Toma | Deja | Apellido | Nombre |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 03:15 | 09:05 | Perez | Juan |

list2:

| Tren | Referencia | Origen | Sale | Destino | Llega | Observaciones |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7404 | X | LLV | 04:06 | PC | 05:51 |  |
| 3009 |  | PC | 05:06 | ZZ | 05:51 | PD |

y asi se repite con otros datos

list1:

| Turno | Toma | Deja | Apellido | Nombre |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 03:15 | 09:05 | Perez | Juan |

list2:

| Tren | Referencia | Origen | Sale | Destino | Llega | Observaciones |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7404 | X | LLV | 04:06 | PC | 05:51 |  |
| 3009 |  | PC | 05:06 | ZZ | 05:51 | PD |

list1:

| Turno | Toma | Deja | Apellido | Nombre |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 03:15 | 09:05 | Perez | Juan |

list2:

| Tren | Referencia | Origen | Sale | Destino | Llega | Observaciones |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7404 | X | LLV | 04:06 | PC | 05:51 |  |
| 3009 |  | PC | 05:06 | ZZ | 05:51 | PD |

El template Jinja2 (que no me funciona) sería este:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block header %} <h1 class="header-h1">{%
block title %}Buscador de trenes{% endblock %}</h1> {% endblock %} {%
block content %}' <div class="top-bar">
    <form method="get">
        <input name="search" type="text" autofocus placeholder="Queres buscar un tren?" />
        <input type="date" id="fecha" name="fecha" onclick="" value="22/06/2021" class="mt-4 form-control">
    </form>
    {% block action %}{% endblock %} {% if trenes or turno %}
    <ul>
       
        <hr> {% for cadaTurno in turnos %} {% for turno in cadaTurno %} {% for dato in Turno %}
        <li class='itinerario'></li>
        <div class="container">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <th>Turno</th>
                    <th>Toma</th>
                    <th>Deja</th>
                    <th>Apellido</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for jornada in dato %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ jornada['Tren']}} </td>
                        <td>{{ jornada['Toma']}} </td>
                        <td>{{ jornada['Deja']}} </td>
                        <td>{{ jornada['Apellido']}} </td>
                        <td>{{ jornada['Nombre']}} </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        </li>
        {% endfor %} {% for j in dato %}
        <li class='itinerario'></li>
        <div class="container">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <th>Tren</th>
                    <th>Referencia</th>
                    <th>Origen</th>
                    <th>Sale</th>
                    <th>Destino</th>
                    <th>Llega</th>
                    <th>Observaciones</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for j in dato %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ j['Tren']}} </td>
                        <td>{{ j['Referencia']}} </td>
                        <td>{{ j['Origen']}} </td>
                        <td>{{ j['Sale']}} </td>
                        <td>{{ j['Destino']}} </td>
                        <td>{{ j['Llega']}} </td>
                        <td>{{ j['Observaciones']}} </td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        </li>
        {% endfor %} {% endfor %} {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %} </div> {% endblock %}
```

Comment: ¿Estás usando algún lenguaje de templates como Jinja, o generas el HTML "a pelo" generando cadenas en python?

Comment: estoy usando Jinja2

Comment: ¿puedes poner el código del template que estás intentando, aunque no funcione bien? Para no tener que empezar de cero...

Comment: listo, igual me quedo un for ahi que no va.

Comment: me daba error y no me dejaba guardar los cambios, tuve que poner la comillas simples al codigo. y hay partes que no me las toma. por eso lo habia subido en jpg

Comment: ahi lo subi como una cita en bloque

Comment: He editado la pregunta para que el código del template salga correctamente formateado, por lo que he eliminado la imagen

Comment: Buenísimo! mil gracias. discúlpame pero soy nuevo en esto y no sabia como hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que buscas es lo que en python hace la función `zip()`. Esta función recibe dos o más listas y devuelve un iterable que las agrupa. Al iterar por el iterable que te devuelve, la primera iteración te da una tupla que contiene tantos elementos como listas le hayas pasado, y en concreto tendrá el primer elemento de cada lista. La siguiente iteración te dará el segundo elemento de cada lista, etc.

Es decir, si en la variable `turnos` tienes la lista1 de tu ejemplo, y en la variable `trenes` tienes la lista2 de tu ejemplo, entonces haciendo un:

```py
for turno, itinerario in zip(turnos, trenes):
```

te irá devolviendo parejas de (turno, itinerario) tomando cada uno de cada una de las listas.

Solo necesitamos poder usar eso mismo en jinja. Por suerte a jinja le puedes pasar al template funciones python, además de variables, así que le podemos pasar la función `zip` así:

```py
render_template("tablas.html", turnos=list1, trenes=list2, zip=zip)
```

El template "tablas.html" (adaptado del que has puesto) sería así:

```html
  {% extends 'base.html' %} {% block header %} {% block title %}Buscador de trenes{% endblock %} {% endblock %} {% block content %} {% block action %}{% endblock %}
  {% if trenes or turnos %}
    {% for tabla1, tabla2 in zip(turnos, trenes) %}
    <hr>
    <li class='itinerario'>Turno {{loop.index}}</li>
    <div class="container">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>Turno</th>
                <th>Toma</th>
                <th>Deja</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for jornada in tabla1 %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ jornada['Tren']}} </td>
                    <td>{{ jornada['Toma']}} </td>
                    <td>{{ jornada['Deja']}} </td>
                    <td>{{ jornada['Apellido']}} </td>
                    <td>{{ jornada['Nombre']}} </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li class='itinerario'>Itinerario {{loop.index}} </li>
    <div class="container">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <th>Tren</th>
                <th>Referencia</th>
                <th>Origen</th>
                <th>Sale</th>
                <th>Destino</th>
                <th>Llega</th>
                <th>Observaciones</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for j in tabla2 %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ j['Tren']}} </td>
                    <td>{{ j['Referencia']}} </td>
                    <td>{{ j['Origen']}} </td>
                    <td>{{ j['Sale']}} </td>
                    <td>{{ j['Destino']}} </td>
                    <td>{{ j['Llega']}} </td>
                    <td>{{ j['Observaciones']}} </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %} </div> {% endblock %}
```

Observa la parte interesante:

```
    {% for tabla1, tabla2 in zip(turnos, trenes) %}
```

Cada iteración de este bucle te dará en `tabla1` lo que tienes que mostrar en la tabla de turnos, y en `tabla2` lo que tienes que mostrar en la tabla de itinerarios. He añadido en los `<li>` que van delante de cada tabla, código para ayudar a la depuración, que muestran el número de turno/itinerario.

Si por ejemplo `list1` y `list2` las inicializo así:

```py
list1 = [
  [{'Turno': '3', 'Toma': '03:15', 'Deja': '09:05', 'Apellido': 'Lopez', 'Nombre': 'Juan'}],
  [{'Turno': '2', 'Toma': '03:15', 'Deja': '09:05', 'Apellido': 'Lanas', 'Nombre': 'Luisa'}]
  ]
list2 = [
[
  {'Tren': 7404, 'Referencia': 'X', 'Origen': 'LLV', 'Sale': '4:06:00', 'Destino': 'PC', 'Llega': '4:34:00', 'Observaciones': None}, 
  {'Tren': 3009, 'Referencia': None, 'Origen': 'PC', 'Sale': '5:06:00', 'Destino': 'ZZ', 'Llega': '5:51:00', 'Observaciones': 'PD'}, 
  {'Tren': 3042, 'Referencia': None, 'Origen': 'ZZ', 'Sale': '6:09:00', 'Destino': 'PC', 'Llega': '7:02:00', 'Observaciones': None}, 
  {'Tren': 3057, 'Referencia': None, 'Origen': 'PC', 'Sale': '7:30:00', 'Destino': 'ZZ', 'Llega': '8:15:00', 'Observaciones': 'PD'}, 
  {'Tren': 3090, 'Referencia': None, 'Origen': 'ZZ', 'Sale': '8:33:00', 'Destino': 'LLV', 'Llega': '8:46:00', 'Observaciones': 'R/O 518'}],
[
  {'Tren': 1234, 'Referencia': 'X', 'Origen': 'LLV', 'Sale': '4:06:00', 'Destino': 'PC', 'Llega': '4:34:00', 'Observaciones': None}, 
  {'Tren': 4321, 'Referencia': None, 'Origen': 'PC', 'Sale': '5:06:00', 'Destino': 'ZZ', 'Llega': '5:51:00', 'Observaciones': 'PD'}, 
  {'Tren': 5678, 'Referencia': None, 'Origen': 'ZZ', 'Sale': '6:09:00', 'Destino': 'PC', 'Llega': '7:02:00', 'Observaciones': None}, 
  {'Tren': 8765, 'Referencia': None, 'Origen': 'PC', 'Sale': '7:30:00', 'Destino': 'ZZ', 'Llega': '8:15:00', 'Observaciones': 'PD'}, 
  {'Tren': 9999, 'Referencia': None, 'Origen': 'ZZ', 'Sale': '8:33:00', 'Destino': 'LLV', 'Llega': '8:46:00', 'Observaciones': 'R/O 666'}]
]
```

el resultado de renderizar el template (con un poco de css para que las tablas salgan más bonitas) sería:

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Ah, un detalle es que las listas han de tener la misma longitud, pues `zip()` deja de iterar en cuanto una se termina. Si necesitas que siga iterando hasta que la más larga se agote, debes usar `itertools.zip_longest()`

Comment: Buenísimo, había encontrado lo de zip acá mismo en StackOverflow pero al querer implementarlo en el témplate me daba error y lo había descartado. muchas gracias!

Comment: Disculpa, ayer no tuve tiempo de probarlo,
me da el siguiente Error:

Proyecto\app\templates\todo\buscador-trenes.html", line 43, in block "content"
{% for tabla1, tabla2 in zip(turnos, trenes) %}
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'zip' is undefined

Comment: pero le has pasado `zip` a `render_template()` como muestro al principio?

Comment: si, omití pasar el zip=zip. Gracias nuevamente!

Comment: No hay de qué. Si esta respuesta resuelve tu problema puedes marcarla como aceptada.